# C# is fantastic, if only List 'd respect Remove&Return

Tags: java, c#, array, collections, list

In the domain of system-modeling (e, systemVerilog, matlab, phyton), lists are obsoleting arrays, stacks and queues(*) altogether. Other domains that use python, perl and ruby have that same mindset, as well.
I am a system-modeler and a List aficionado that is new to c# and java (for hi-school teaching). c# seem so great ..but...

**The *Remove&Return* approach is respected by :**

C# *Stack*, C# *Queue*, Java *ArrayList* ,Python *list*, Perl, Ruby, e, systemverilog and others.

**A notable exception is ... C# List.**

`c#` `List<T>.RemoveAt(idx)`  doesn't return a value.

**Why is that important ?** 
Say one wants to post this in a *modeling* **web** site (who aren't experts in c#):

```
 int len=myCriticalProcessList.Length; sendMethod( myCriticalProcessList.RemoveAt(len - 1)  );
```

That seem to work  for any modern language, but to post it in c#, one has to also post several more lines, and invent new names. 
Also one doesn't need to know the type of the list!   And when the type is changed, he does not need to change his code at all. Also naturally System modeling folks care about advanced c#, as much as c# folks care about advanced system-modeling (i.e none).

Can there be any damage if a value is returned in that case?
Is there a performance consideration here?
Does Java-value-return in arraylist.remove, make it slower, or less safe?
Is c#'s ***remove&return approach*** good for `Stack`, and `Queue`, yet not a good idea for `List`? 
Is there some difference in underline implementation, or philosophy ?

Side note:

- `C# Stack.Pop` and `c# Queue.Dequeue` do return a value. (a
  remove&return approach, like Java remove, and unlike c# RemoveAt).
- Python's `list.pop([idx])`,  *removes-element-by-position*,
  *and* returns a value. Similar to `remove` in `java` ( yet with a default, remove&return the *last* element).
- C++ (stl) remove, is also void (thanks @Deduplicator). Yet, decisions relevant for languages without native-built-in-garbage-collection, are not always relevant for GC langs.

***Seem @Deduplicator comment points us to the answer!!***

C# was inspired by c++ not only in it's name, but also in many other things.Additionally, C# compiler was developed in C++ (in it's first ~15 years). Find me one human that is not influenced by the language he is using ...
No one says it's better than Mads Torgersen, the program manager of c# :  "Working in C# every day makes you think differently about C#: It’s the power of “dogfooding”."
https://medium.com/microsoft-open-source-stories/how-microsoft-rewrote-its-c-compiler-in-c-and-made-it-open-source-4ebed5646f98

(*) minor: queues are not 100% obliterated by lists. There're very rare cases in system modeling  were O(n) for dequeue is *not* tolerated.

Comment: Well, any authoritative answer is going to have to come from the design team themselves, so you're unlikely to find that here.  Nevertheless, that doesn't prevent me from idly speculating.  Intuitively, stacks and queues are specifically designed to add and remove things in a queue-like way, whereas List is not; it's simply a list.  Note that Python's instruction is not `remove`, it is `pop`.  In any case, Java's preference to return the removed item in an ArrayList is just that: a preference, easily remedied in C# by simply getting the item from the list before removing it.

Comment: The 'instruction'  has different name on different languages- sure. (remove,RemoveAt,delete,pop, shift )  yet the **concept** of  Remove&Return seem to be respected regardless of the language. Except for c# List, where the **concept** is not respected.

Comment: @rankeren: The issue isnt in concept vs instruction. The issue is that the only people who can answer this question are the people who made the decision. There is no objective reason why to return a value or not. The only meaningful answer can come from whoever made the arbitrary decision, so the question is a bad fit for a public Q&A site.

Comment: @Flater, well there could be someone with insights, or even a way for the community, to ask c# designers why they decided  different from  any other language. Mircosoft folks may read this site.and an answer will be interesting to many.

Comment: @rankeren: Questions that have only one correct answer are fine (and are, in fact, encouraged over subjective questions). Questions that have only one possible _answerer_ are not fine by StackExchange's standards.

Comment: You might want to read on [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). The decision to return the removed value or not is probably a question of pragmatism. Note that `Stack.pop` violating the CQS principle is a notorious example as you wouldn't be able to implement `pop` while respecting the principle.

Comment: @Flater as the implementation in C# is open, various smart folks may understand it, and may answer the performance question and the safety question.  Other folks used to C# mindset, could answer the philosophical question and give color.

Comment: @rankeren: Having access to the source code shows you _that_ it behaves this way, it does not show you **why** it behaves this way.

Comment: @Flater, indeed. That is why i said performance, and safety.  Minset/philosophy is not from that source code, but from longtime experience in that platform, which i lack.

Comment: While we can't definitely speak for others, it does seem reasonable to ask for probable explanations behind simple design decisions.  Whether or not these explanations actually represent the thoughts of the designer seems beside the point, since the actual concern isn't so much for the designer's personal thoughts so much as to understand the widespread acceptance of a well-known design.

Comment: @Nat: Not everything has been proven to be the best choice (or to elicit a particular outcome) if no one cared about it at the time- or there was no real choice to be made at the time. It reminds me of the old joke with the child who is taught by her mother that your should always cut a sausage in two before frying it. Mom doesn't know why, but it's what her mom told her. They ask grandma, who says the same thing, her mom told her. They ask the great grandmother, who finally reveals that she used to only have a very small frying pan.

Comment: @Nat: "Why do we cut sausage in two?" is like "Why is this code like this?". The originating source (the great grandmother) can answer it. Everyone else can only say "because that's what it is", or bring forth their own speculation on why it should be done this way. But they cannot actually _answer_ the question, which is the quality standard that StackExchange uphold for their Q&A.

Comment: @Flater: Definitely true.  And if this particular design decision doesn't have a plausible motivation, then a good answer ought to point that out.  Likewise, if this design decision would seem mistaken, a good answer could offer criticism and discuss a better solution.  That such an answer wouldn't reflect on the actual designer's personal thinking would be okay since, in reality, we don't typically care.

Comment: @Nat _"a good answer could offer criticism and discuss a better solution"_ You have just struck upon exactly that which StackExchange prohibitis: subjective criticism and discussion. There are contextual exceptions to this (e.g. Code Review), but the general goal is to avoid non-objective answers and criticisms.

Comment: @Flater: Yup, any criticism should be objective, just like everything else.

Comment: @Flater: For example, say someone asks if they should use a concurrent lock or not in a specific scenario; we can objectively answer that based on the need.  Then, say someone else asks why a concurrent lock was included in some specific code sample; then, we may interpret that as asking why doing so would've been a correct response to the first question, or else why it wouldn't have been correct.  Why the actual programmer decided to include a lock at the moment of typing the code isn't the relevant issue.

Comment: @Flater  what is subjective in :  Does Java-value-return in arraylist.remove, make it slower, or less safe?

Comment: Similar x-site questions  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982597/why-doesnt-c-sharp-linkedlist-removefirst-return-the-removed-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432248/why-does-the-generic-list-addrange-return-void-instead-of-a-list

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: wow f-a-n-t-a-s-t-i-c refs, relevant, wise, inspiring . I also wonder why community accepted their, very similar in spirit, questions on c# collections api, and rejected mine...

Comment: @rankeren: The first sentence of the accepted answer in your first link is *"I can't really give a definitive answer, as I can't read the minds of the designers of `LinkedList<T>`"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey,   so what you are saying is that those other useful, inspiring links should have been rejected as well.

Comment: Gosh, I'm pretty sure I didn't actually say that.  And your premise is invalid; closing questions doesn't constitute rejection.

Comment: Regarding your edit ("if only"): why don't you just write a method  that removes and returns the item from the list?  It would take about five lines of code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey,  'm  interested in the  thought process of  compiler teams and historical trends on sw development philosophy.   Additionally i think that platform should serve us.   However  you can close it as answered.  They copied C++ ( see edit to the question,  usr @ Deduplicator gave the lead)

Comment: Familiarity is often the reason things are done in programming languages.  Sometimes, it can be the only reason.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, people remove things from lists already knowing what those things are, as that knowledge is why they want to remove the item in the first place.  By contrast, people don't usually want to remove specific known items from a stack/queue, but rather retrieve the first/last element.

Probably relevant factors:

1. **Consistency with `List<T>.Remove(T)`.**
   A `List<T>` has a `.Remove(T)` method that returns a `bool` indicating if the removal was successful.  So, for consistency, we'd expect `.RemoveAt(int)` to do the same.  Except `.RemoveAt(int)` can't really fail (unless the index is out-of-range, in which case it throws an exception instead), so it just returns `void` instead.
2. **Removing an item from a list doesn't imply retrieval.**
   Queues/stacks are all about specific process models in which things are queued/stacked and then dequeued/popped for processing, such that removal and retrieval are conceptually linked together.  By contrast, lists don't inherently imply such an operational model.
3. **Retrieval is readily available for when someone would want it.**
   If a caller would want to retrieve the item at the index before removing it, then they can just specify that with `list[index]`.

It's worth noting that a hypothetical `ConcurrentList<T>` would've probably implemented

```
partial public class ConcurrentList<T>
{
    public bool TryRemoveAt(
                int targetIndex
            ,   out T successfullyRemovedItem
        )
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

, analogous to a similar `.TryRemove(T_Key, out T_Value)` for `ConcurrentDictionary<T_Key, T_Value>`'s.

Finally, the main use-case of `List.RemoveAt()` is probably something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < list.count; ++i)
{
    if (someConditionalCheck(list[i]))
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

, where it's important to note that `break;`, since if the loop continues without breaking after removal, then it'll skip an element.  This could be fixed by also manually decrementing `i`, e.g. `--i` instead of `break;`, but at that point the code's getting pretty twisted.  Plus it'd be poor form to try something like this without a `break;`, anyway, as list-removal is O(*n*), making it a poor choice of data structure to use if someone expects to loop over multiple removals as that could be O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: "Typically, people remove things from lists already knowing what those things are"- in  my tech domain, for 20 years, that is absolutely *not* the case.   In  Chip /System modeling/verification ,  removing  items from a collection ( fifo or lifo) , is very common.   Of course, you are unaware what the item is, before it's removed.   Everyone I know (been in many teams) uses  a list for such a collection, as lists offer flexibility, and are the de facto standard in System verification domain.  It is not only java, but seem every language with lists, supports remove&return.

Comment: @rankeren C++ does not. Admittedly, that allows non-movable elements.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Man, you found the reason !  C# was inspired by C++ (in many things, not only it's name).  I have no idea what a 'non-movable element' is. Is that term relevant for languages with build-in,native garbage collection ?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I think you nailed it !!  C# was developed in C++ (in it's first ~15 years). Obviously, the developers where influenced by it. Mads Torgersen : "Working in C# every day makes you think differently about C#: It’s the power of “dogfooding”. https://medium.com/microsoft-open-source-stories/how-microsoft-rewrote-its-c-compiler-in-c-and-made-it-open-source-4ebed5646f98

Comment: Nice theory. In practice, there were different teams writing the C# compiler (in C++) and the BCL, including the `List` class (in C#)

Comment: The classes, such as `List` are not part of C#; they are part of the .NET base class library. So you’d need to ask the creators of the BCL, why they wrote `List` the way they did. And as I pointed out in my answer to your near identical question from a couple of weeks ago, adding your own extension method to the list classes is trivial, so your question is largely irrelevant save for niche academic interest.

Comment: @DavidArno: i received a private comment from the site, asking me to separate that older question into several,  more focused, independent questions. As the policy of the site, is *not* to mix several questions in one post.  So i researched deeper into  'RemoveAt' issue, at many languages. yet the one one language i neglected ( as not even having lists, nor GC) - C++ could had been the critical one.

Comment: @rankeren I haven't had time to read through the comments in detail, but I suspect that the folks you're referring to are using lists without thinking through what type of collection they should actually be using.  In which case it's sorta like asking why a hammer isn't good at removing screws, noting that everyone at a company uses hammers to remove screws.. it's just the wrong tool, ya know?

Comment: @rankeren I mean, if you want to modify C# to have a `List<>` return the removed item when removing it, you can easily do that with an extension method in a few lines of code.  But before doing so, you may want to ensure that the right kind of collection is being used.  (Noting that lists _aren't_ the most powerful kind of collection; they're actually fairly primitive, being a step-up from an array.)

Comment: @rankeren Practically speaking, you may want to ask another question describing how you're using lists to ask for feedback on if it's using the right kind of collection.  Using the right sort of collection for the job may make your life easier, plus improve the performance, reliability, and maintainability of your code.

Comment: @nat: most teams in the domain of system modeling and verification,  use *only * lists, for many years. Consulting to such projects for 20 years in tens of companies, and often profiling, I never saw an issue with that. (except once). The reason is that there are other way slower operations, and that usually lists are short.

Comment: Even for long lists, pop works fast, and only pop0 (dequeue) may cause issues. Indeed ,  pop0 killed the performance, but only one time. As list was huge, and pop0 was every cycle. Interesting, even in that case, there was non need for queue. As the list was a huge sdh frame, generated once (list of bytes) . Solution was just to reverse it once, and use pop

Comment: @rankeren Unfortunately that's just poor coding.  Which I don't mean to insult your coworkers, just.. it's really just like someone saying that their peers all use hammers to remove screws; what else could one make of that?

Comment: Nat:  when  lists are short,  and the processes are 10000000 heavier,  that style rules . An entire industry,  ( at least 20000 engineers at the intel's of the world )  do  exactly that. Some of languages in the domain, do not even natively support pop0 in O1. Surprisingly , 20 years in the domain, and did lots of performance profiling, only once had that been an issue, and even in that case there was no need for queue. Just to reverse that list once after generating it, and use pop, that is  O1.

Comment: @rankeren: That's unfortunate; it's a technical debt that you're currently paying interest on as it's apparently too large for anyone to pay off in full now.  But given your situation, you can add a C# extension method.  It's just a few lines of code, and it'll give you the functionality you want.  You may want to consider asking another question seeking a better solution.

Comment: Nat: I think we should take it off line.  Note that that I have read a lot about 'your industry' i. e.  c# and collections before posting, and I will be happy to supply you with  enough knowledge  on system modeling, so that your comments on this domain would be even more relevant.  Skype: rankeren

Comment: @nat:  premature optimization is the root of all evil.  D. Knuth.